# How to Save Results from Foreach into Txt File

Tags: php, foreach, fopen

I would like to write all files from specific folder into .txt file. The output working just fine, but I'm getting only one file saved into my txt file. Any idea? Thanks!

```
$fileList = glob('C:\users\John\Documents\*pdf');
foreach($fileList as $filename){
if(is_file($filename)){
echo $filename, '<br>'; 

$save_files = fopen("list.txt", "wb");
fwrite($save_files,$filename);
fclose($save_files);

}   
}
```

Comment: You are opening the file with `"wb"` - *Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it...

```
foreach($fileList as $filename){
if(is_file($filename)){
echo $filename, '<br>'; 

$list[] = $filename;
      }   
}

$capture = implode("\r\n",$list);

file_put_contents("list.txt",$capture);
```